# snowflake: how to get all the users who were granted a particular role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake i have a role `XYZ`

I want to view all the `users` who are granted this role `XYZ` using `sql` commands.

How can i do this.

I know we have

```
SHow roles

show users

show grants
```

Can we use the above and get what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to list all users and roles to which role XYZ was granted:

```
SHOW GRANTS OF role XYZ
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html